# Opentok not reconnect always

Tags: android, opentok

I'm currently working on a chat application where I'm using OpenTok `text-chat signal api`. The problem I'm facing is that when there is drop in network the `api` try to reconnect for very short period of time if `api` not able to reconnect in that short period of time `error` callback called followed by session disconnect. After that `api` remains always disconnected.

Is is possible to make `api` to call reconnect again? or any method to set ot increase reconnection timeout?

Answer (score 1):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

The OpenTok Android SDK attempts to reconnect for 30 seconds, but if the SDK is unable to reconnect within 30 seconds, the SDK does not attempt to reconnect.

As of today, we do not have an API to set the reconnection time so you would have to call the `connect` method again.